# Integrality Gap in MAXIMIZATION in CPLEX+Java | Bug?

Tags: java, cplex

I try to solve a large MIP in which the . If it does not solve optimally, it shall return the integrality gap (that is, difference between best integer solution and best solution of the linear relaxation). 
Using `getMIPRelativeGap` of the Java+CPLEX interface, I sometimes got values in the range of 1.0E11-1.0E13 which does not make sense, as an integrality gap should be a percentage between 0 and 1. I tracked those cases down and found out that I get those results, if the best integer solution has a value of 0 (my inner problem is a profitable tour problem, thus, if the best route is not visiting any vertice). The integrality gap should be `(bestobjective-bestinteger)/bestobjective` (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refdotnetcplex/html/M_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_MIPInfoCallback_GetMIPRelativeGap.htm), yet, it seems to be `(bestobjective-bestinteger)/bestinteger`. 
I also tested a couple of other values (if the integer objective is positive), and were able to confirm this in examples.

Can someone else reproduce this behavior? Does this behavior make sense to you?

Thanks :)

Comment: When you get the unexpected mip gap, what is the solution status (i.e., the value of [getStatus()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html?view=kc#getStatus()))?

Comment: example: 
best objective = 447.4199223
best integer = 424.8186313
status = feasible

the integrality gap should be (in my interpretation): 0.050515 = (objective-integer)/objective
CPLEX returns the following integrality gap: 0.053202 = (objective-integer)/integer

Comment: the status is also feasible, if no integer solution except "no movement" is found (which is a feasible solution to my problem). in this case, it returns gaps in the order of E12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/getmiprelgap.html) for `CPXgetmiprelgap` in the Callable Library (C API) says the following:

> For a **minimization** problem, this value is computed by
>
> (bestinteger - bestobjective) / (1e-10 + |bestinteger|)
>
> where bestinteger is the value returned by `CPXXgetobjval/CPXgetobjval`
>   and bestobjective is the value returned by
>   `CPXXgetbestobjval/CPXgetbestobjval`. For a **maximization** problem,
>   the value is computed by:
>
> (bestobjective - bestinteger) / (1e-10 + |bestinteger|)

So, it looks like the *documentation* for the Java API is buggy. The Java API just calls `CPXgetmiprelgap` under the hood, so it should be the same. Thanks for reporting this. I'll make sure that this gets passed on to the folks who can fix it.